# How to create programming flowchart/documentation from VB.NET source code?

Tags: vb.net, documentation, documentation-generation

what tools do you use to create programming flowchart/documentation from VB.NET source code? There are absolutely no comments/documentation at present. I am a beginner, i.e. I tried Sandcastle but it is way over my head and could not get it going, not even with GUI.
Fatesoft's CodeVisual To Flowchart is OK but it is almost the same as the code and I still don't understand the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Convert VB.NET to Csharp using http://converter.telerik.com/
2. Use Code Rocket to both generate documentation and flowchart  http://www.rapidqualitysystems.com/Products/CodeRocketNET

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in XML documentation, described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172652.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have always enjoyed the output of [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)

And now I read that you need it for VB .... sigh

I guess you can look at it and think about how awesome it would have been to use ;)

Comment: yeah, I know - I checked it out before I posted the question